# The button images get corrupted and overflow from the background image In my python code

Tags: kivy

I have this code that creates a menu screen for a game using kivy:

```py
# Setting the window size and scaling
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1080')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1920')
Window.size = (1080, 1920)

class NineStonesApp(App):
    # Defining the attributes of the class
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Inheriting the attributes of the App class
        super(NineStonesApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Setting the window size to 1080x1920
        Window.size = (1080, 1920)
        # Creating a screen manager
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        # Creating the menu and game screens
        self.menu_screen = MenuScreen(name="menu")
        self.game_screen = GameScreen(name="game")
        # Adding the screens to the screen manager
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.menu_screen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.game_screen)

# Defining the function that will run when the app starts
    def build(self):
        # Returning the screen manager
        print("build Function is Running")
        return self.screen_manager

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    # Defining the attributes of the class
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Inheriting the attributes of the Screen class
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
# Creating an image that shows the background of the menu screen
        self.background = Image(source="images/background.png", pos=(0, 0), size=(1080, 1920))
        
# Creating a button for single player game selection
        self.single_button = Button(background_normal="images/single.png", background_down="images/single.png", pos=(150, 500), size=(100, 100), size_hint=(None, None))

        # Binding a function to start the single player game when the button is pressed
        self.single_button.bind(on_press=self.start_single)
        
# Creating a button for double player game selection
        self.double_button = Button(background_normal="images/double.png", background_down="images/double.png", pos=(300, 500), size=(150, 150), size_hint=(None, None))
        # Binding a function to start the double player game when the button is pressed
        self.double_button.bind(on_press=self.start_double)
       
 # Creating a button for online game selection
        self.online_button = Button(background_normal="images/online.png", background_down="images/online.png", pos=(450, 500), size=(200, 200), size_hint=(None, None))
        # Binding a function to start the online game when the button is pressed
        self.online_button.bind(on_press=self.start_online)
       
 # Adding the background image to the screen
        self.add_widget(self.background)
        
# Adding the buttons to the screen
        self.add_widget(self.single_button)
        self.add_widget(self.double_button)
        self.add_widget(self.online_button)
        print("Menuscreen Function is Running")
```

I expect this code to fit the screen in 1080: 1920 resolution and I want the images I uploaded to not be distorted when I change their size in the application, but there are black spaces on the right and left edges of the image and the buttons appear in those areas. When I want to change the positions of the buttons, their shape is distorted. What is the reason? Thanks for your answers (This is my first post so apologies if i did something wrong & I would appreciate it if you could explain it simply because my English is not good) (background.png is 1080:1920 too)